# Install Kafka docker image on windows 10 (in Windows Container mode)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-image, windows-container

I am trying to install Kafka docker image on windows 10, but it is always saying "image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform".

Note: I am in "Windows container mode".

Although, if I change the docker setting "Switch to Linux containers", then there are  various images on docker like spotify/kafka, wurstmeister/kafka which I am able to install.

Question:
Do we have an image of kafka on docker hub which can be install on windows while in Winodws Container mode?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the kafka image you are trying to pull from Dockerhub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find one - I think the reasons are:

- Everyone uses Kafka on linux for production
- Supporting all flavours of Windows container requires a bunch of tags
- Linux containers work with Docker CE

That said, I made a dev/test windows container dockerfile for kafka which I've [shared on GitHub](https://github.com/peterwishart/kafka-dockeree), and you can build locally.